# Saving Array of Object in CloudKit

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, cloudkit

I'm coding a Game and at this point I have some array of many objects.
At this moment, I coded for save/read/update only single variables.
How can I save these arrays on CloudKit?

For example, this is a type of array that I need to save:

```
let example1 = [String, Date, Bool, Int, Image]

let example2 = [String, Date, Bool, Int, Image]

let arrayToSave = [example1, example2]
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: You may want to reorganize data, but otherwise the only way to do it (besides saving each component individually) would be to serialize the array and save it as data. However, this is fairly inefficient and poor design.

Comment: @milesper I think he is asking how he might reorganize the data.

Comment: Did you find solution for this?